# Is it OK if dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: gets called before presentModalViewControllerAnimated:?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, dismiss

I'm doing:

```
if (navigationController.visibleViewController == passcodeInputNav) {
    [navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Is the condition unnecessary? Can I just do:

```
[navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

What happens if there's no modal view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going with:

```
[navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

without the if statement because it works whether or not the modal view controller has been presented.